# Draw border around GLControl - openTK winform

Tags: c#, winforms, opengl, border, onpaint

I'm using a glcontrol for showing continues frames from a video. Now I want to draw a border around this glcontrol. I have done like below. But when resizing or changing the location of the glcontrol this border is not coming. How can I solve this?

```
private void glControl1_Paint_1(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    ControlPaint.DrawBorder(e.Graphics, this.glControl1.ClientRectangle,   
    Color.White, 3, ButtonBorderStyle.Solid,
    Color.White, 3, ButtonBorderStyle.Solid,
    Color.White, 3, ButtonBorderStyle.Solid,
    Color.White, 3, ButtonBorderStyle.Solid);                                                                                           
}

private void comboBox1Resolution_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (comboBox1Resolution.SelectedIndex != -1)
    {
        videoSource1.VideoResolution =videoSource1.VideoCapabilities[comboBox1Resolution.SelectedIndex];                               
        OpenGL_SizeChanged(videoSource1);//changing size and location of glcontrol          
    }
}
```